# Anonymizing or masking PII data in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, gdpr

How do I mask or anonymize PII data in Marketing Cloud?  I don't want to do a full Contact Delete as I want to keep the contact record for tracking and reporting purposes.  However, I want all PII like name, email address, phone number, etc. to be masked/anonymized or deleted in all of Marketing Cloud.

I've already looked at Subscriber delete and that anonymizes PII but that just removes them from Email Studio and not all of Marketing Cloud.

I'm looking to do this on a weekly basis so I'm looking for an automated solution if possible.

Comment: This sounds like a possible use case for Field-Level Encryption - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_field_level_encryption.htm&type=5. It will make all your attributes, etc. encrypted and unable to be viewed inside the platform, but will let them function as normal inside the system. E.g. still sendable and trackable

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: A note on this.  It's a separate SKU from Salesforce to get this enabled.  Fairly certain it operates as a hash, so there's no going back after you've implemented FLE.  Also, fairly certain it's enterprise wide, so you cannot apply it to specific business units.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Contact Delete for any of those? After you delete contact using Contact Delete, the tracking will still show in the Data Views (6 months). From that point (deleted Contact) the tracking will relate to Subscriber Key only. Because all data associated to the Contact has been deleted, the Subscriber Key data becomes anonymized per se.